# PHP: Parse error, unexpected $end

Tags: php

Basically, Its a login form. I want it to only show the login form, when a user session exists (that is when he is logged in). But I am getting the following error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\xampp\htdocs\zabis\index.php on line 113
```

Code is given below:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);

require 'connect.php';
require 'functions.php';

session_name('tzLogin');
// Starting the session

session_set_cookie_params(2*7*24*60*60);
// Making the cookie live for 2 weeks

session_start();

if($_SESSION['id'] && !isset($_COOKIE['tzRemember']) && !$_SESSION['rememberMe'])
{
    // If you are logged in, but you don't have the tzRemember cookie (browser restart)
    // and you have not checked the rememberMe checkbox:

    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();

    // Destroy the session
}


if(isset($_GET['logoff']))
{
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();

    header("Location: demo.php");
    exit;
}

if ($_POST['submit']=='login')
{
  $err = array();

  if(!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password'])
                         $err = 'username or password missing!';

  if(!count($err))
  {

    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $rememberMe = (int)$_POST['rememberMe'];


    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,usr FROM members WHERE usr='{$username}' AND pass='".md5($password)."'"));

    if($row['usr'])
    {
      $_SESSION['usr']=$row['usr'];
      $_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
      $_SESSION['rememberMe']=$_POST['rememberMe'];

      //setcookie('tzRemember',$_POST['rememberMe']);

      if($rememberMe=="on")
       setcookie('zsRememberMe',$username, time()+7200);


    }
    else
        $err[] = "wrong username or password!";
  }

  if($err)
   $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br/>',$err);

   header("Location: index.php");
   exit;
}
else
    die("Please enter a username and password.");


?>





<html>
<body>

<?php
            if(!$_SESSION['id']):
            ?>
<div id="content">
  <h1>Login Form</h1>
  <form id="form1" name="form1" action="doLogin.php" method="post">
    <p>
      <label for="username">Username: </label>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="password">Password: </label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
    </p>
    <p/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe"> Remember me
    <p>
      <input type="submit" id="login" name="login" />
    </p>
  </form>
    <div id="message"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're not closing the last `if` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
<?php
        if(!$_SESSION['id']):
        ?>
<div id="content">
<h1>Login Form</h1>
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="doLogin.php" method="post">
<p>
  <label for="username">Username: </label>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
</p>
<p>
  <label for="password">Password: </label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
</p>
<p/>
<input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe"> Remember me
<p>
  <input type="submit" id="login" name="login" />
</p>
</form>
<div id="message"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

to

```
<?php
        if(!$_SESSION['id']):
        ?>
<div id="content">
<h1>Login Form</h1>
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="doLogin.php" method="post">
<p>
  <label for="username">Username: </label>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
</p>
<p>
  <label for="password">Password: </label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
</p>
<p/>
<input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe"> Remember me
<p>
  <input type="submit" id="login" name="login" />
</p>
</form>
<div id="message"></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

note that `<?php endif; ?>`. You have forgotten to close last if statement

Answer (score 3):

Last `if` statement is not closed. Close it by adding:

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

At the end of your code.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: And please close this type of question instead of answering it ;)

Comment: I think it's a valid question, @NikiC I don't see a reason to close it. False ends appear, happens to everyone.

Comment: It's personal debugging for one person -- this question doesn't have any value to anyone else.

Comment: "This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors" -> Too Localized.

Comment: I am a new programmer, it helped me now i realized my mistake. NiKiC you are not kind.